# Jest : window.location.assign mock function not called .. is it related to a Promise catch()?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, jestjs

I am testing the following file

**tests/client/blog.spec.js**

```
    import axios from 'axios';

    import API_BASE from './config';   // '/api/v1/blog/'

    const deletePost = id => {
      console.log('ID: ', id);
      axios.delete(`${API_BASE}/blog/${id}`, {
          headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
          data: null, // data null is necessary to pass the headers
        })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log('AXIOS RESOLVED: ', result);
          window.location.assign('/admin?cache=false');
          console.log('CALLED window.location.assign with /admin?cache=false');
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log('AXIOS REJECTED: ', e);
          window.location.assign('/admin?cache=true');
          console.log('CALLED window.location.assign with /admin?cache=true');
        });
      };

    const setupDeletePostHandler = () => {
      const links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.delete-post'), 0);
      if (links.length > 0) {
        links.forEach(el => {
          el.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.currentTarget.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            e.currentTarget.querySelector('i').classList.remove('is-hidden');
            const id = el.dataset.postId;
            return deletePost(id);
          });
        });
      }
    };

    const pageReady = page => {
      switch (page) {
        case 'admin-index':
          setupDeletePostHandler();
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    };

    export default {
      pageReady,
    };
```

with the following specs :

**tests/client/blog.spec.js**

```
    import Blog from '../../src/client/js/blog.js';

    import mockAxios from "axios";

    jest.mock('axios');

    describe('client/blog', () => {

      beforeAll(() => {
        jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign').mockImplementation(() => {});
      });

      afterEach(() => {
        mockAxios.delete.mockClear();
      });

      afterAll(() => {
        window.location.assign.mockRestore();
      });

      it('set the DeletePostHandler', async function () {
        // WHEN
        const post = '<div class="posts"><div class="post">' +
          '<p>Today should be a great day to be alive!</p>' +
          '<div class="is-hidden">' +
          '<a id="link_1" class="delete-post" href="/admin/edit-post/" data-post-id="">delete<i class="is-hidden"></i></a>' +
          '</div></div>';
        document.body.innerHTML = post;
        Blog.pageReady('admin-index');
        // WHEN
        await document.querySelector('#link_1').click();
        // THEN
        expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalled();
        console.log('CALLS: ', window.location.assign.mock.calls);
        expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/admin?cache=false');
      });

    });
```

it(s failing, here is the console :

**__mocks__/axios.js**

```
    export default {
      delete: jest.fn((url) => {
        if (url === '/api/v1/blog/1') {
            return Promise.resolve({
              data: {},
              status: 200,
              statusText: 'OK',
              headers: {}
            });
        } else {
          return Promise.reject({
            data: {},
            status: 400,
            statusText: 'Error',
            headers: {}
          });
        }
      })
    };
```

**console.log**

```
    $ yarn test-client
    yarn run v1.9.4
    $ jest tests/client/*.js
     FAIL  tests/client/blog.spec.js
      client/blog
        ✕ set the DeletePostHandler (47ms)

      ● client/blog › set the DeletePostHandler

        expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

        Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

          33 |     // THEN
          34 |     expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        > 35 |     expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalled();
             |                                    ^
          36 |     console.log('CALLS: ', window.location.assign.mock.calls);
          37 |     expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/admin?cache=false');
          38 |   });

          at Object.toHaveBeenCalled (tests/client/blog.spec.js:35:36)
          at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
          at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
          at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
          at step (tests/client/blog.spec.js:22:191)
          at tests/client/blog.spec.js:22:361

      console.log src/client/js/blog.js:7
        ID:

      console.log src/client/js/blog.js:18
        AXIOS REJECTED:  { data: {}, status: 400, statusText: 'Error', headers: {} }

      console.log src/client/js/blog.js:20
        CALLED window.location.assign with /admin?cache=true
```

Strange ... the log, shows that upon Axios request rejected, the mock function should be called ... bit it's not

Note:  When I test the script with Axios request being resolved, then the window.location.assign mock is correctly called ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into similar issues in the past.

### Issue

`catch` hasn't executed by the time `expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalled()` runs and fails.

### Details

`click()` doesn't actually return anything so `await` has nothing to wait on.

In my experience calling `await` allows for one cycle of the [`PromiseJobs`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) queue which is why the `then` runs and the test passes if the Axios request resolves.

`catch` seems to take two cycles of the `PromiseJobs` queue so it hasn't executed by the test continues past `await` and fails on the assertion.

### Solution

The solution is to make sure `catch` has run before asserting.

Ideally this is done by returning the `Promise` and `await`-ing it in the test like you are attempting to do.  The tricky part with this test is that `click` doesn't actually return anything so there is no `Promise` to await.

For situations like this where it isn't possible to `await` the actual `Promise` a good workaround is to `await` a resolved `Promise` for the required number of cycles of the `PromiseJobs` queue.

Each time a `Promise` is `await`-ed the rest of the test essentially gets queued at the back of `PromiseJobs` and allows anything already in the queue to run before continuing the test.

In this case, waiting two cycles of the `PromiseJobs` queue will give `catch` a chance to run:

```
document.querySelector('#link_1').click();  // remove "await" since nothing is returned
await Promise.resolve().then();  // wait two cycles of the PromiseJobs queue
// THEN
expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian ! I anticipated such problem but could not identify it ... your comment suggest also that we can learn a lot from unit testing to eventually rewrite the code... "if it's difficult to test , then rewrite your code !" ... whatever it's not a final version of the client code... I use to work with Vue.js ... whatever your answer is very clear and helpful !